# calling HTTP web page in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have this code in my vb.net application:

```
myHttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
                myHttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                If myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                    receivestream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
                    encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")

                    Dim readStream As New StreamReader(receivestream, encode)
                    response = readStream.ReadToEnd()
                    myHttpWebResponse.Close()
                    receivestream.Close()
                    readStream.Close()

                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + vbCrLf + "URL: " + url + vbCrLf + vbCrLf
                    'scroll to bottom
                    TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
                    TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
                    Me.Refresh()
                Else
                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "Could not contact server for: " + url + vbCrLf + vbCrLf
                    'scroll to bottom
                    TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
                    TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
                    Me.Refresh()
                End If
```

sometimes i get `500 internal server` errors or `404 not found`

also if the internet connection goes down that this program is running on i get an error too

the above code is inside a loop. how can i just skip this loop if there is an error

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch outside your loop, and log your errors. You can exit a for loop with a simple Exit keyword. Also you can refactor your code into a single method and just exit that as well.